# How do I map every element in a range with a function?

Tags: matlab, mapping, octave, range-map

I see that I can define a range with `1:3`. I can also apply a function to a number, e.g. `sin(1)`. But, how do I map the range of numbers with the function? I would like to $1,2,3 \to sin(1), sin(2), sin(3)$.

Comment: You can't use that type of markdown on SO. Use backtick for code formatting. I don't understand the question... Can you try to explain it better? Do you want `sin(1:3)`? Can you please accurately explain what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want something like this:

```
[1:n; sin(1:n)].'
ans =
    1.0000    0.8415
    2.0000    0.9093
    3.0000    0.1411
    4.0000   -0.7568
```

or

```
f = @(n) sin(n)
f(1:n)
ans =
    0.8415    0.9093    0.1411   -0.7568
```

I can explain it more thoroughly if you confirm that this is what you want to achieve.